# How do I ensure a sprite is placed in the foreground/middleground/background in my order of preference?

Tags: python, background, pygame, layer, foreground

Essentially, I have written some code for a pygame game, and have blitted some images onto the screen, and some others have been added via a SpriteGroup. This has been done in a procedural order in my mainline - yet it seems that the order of the images in terms of front to back is randomised to an extent.

Having checked my code, I note that the images in conflict are both within the same SpriteGroup.

Is it possible to define the order for images within a SpriteGroup?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to use the [`LayeredUpdates`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) group:

> class **pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates**
>
> *LayeredUpdates is a sprite group that handles layers and draws like OrderedUpdates.*
>   `LayeredUpdates(*spites, **kwargs) -> LayeredUpdates`
>
> This group is fully compatible with pygame.sprite.SpriteSimple base class for visible game objects..
>
> You can set the default layer through kwargs using ‘default_layer’ and an integer for the layer. The default layer is 0.
>
> If the sprite you add has an attribute layer then that layer will be used. If the **kwarg contains ‘layer’ then the sprites passed will be added to that layer (overriding the sprite.layer attribute). If neither sprite has attribute layer nor **kwarg then the default layer is used to add the sprites.